# JSON-simple get JSONObject using method

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have been working on a project that requires JSON for getting data from a large json file, but I ran into a problem when trying to get a json string using a method.
the method for getting the ID works I have tested this multiple times. When I enter int he ID as a string it also works prefectly but when I use the method to get the jsonString it stops working and gives a nullpoiterexeption

```
public static int getLvlMin(ItemStack is) throws ParseException {
    String id = getID(is);
    system.out.println(id);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(Main.weapons);
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
    system.out.printlnjsonObj.toJSONString());
    JSONObject weapon = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get(String.valueOf(getID(is)));
    system.out.println(weapon.toJSONString());
    return 1;
}
```

This is the json string I am trying to get info `{"W1121000-00002":{"clnt":1023,"srvr":870}}` and I am trying to get the `clnt` value out of that string.

Comment: Is your `ItemStack` class a [proper stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))?  And does `getID()` work by popping an element off of it?  If so, the problem is that you're calling `getID()` twice, but probably only have one valid value in the `ItemStack`.

Comment: both those method just return a string. And when I print out that string and enter it in `jsonObj.get("W1121000-00002")` it works fine, but when using the method it doesn't

Comment: Yes, they return a string _and mutate the `ItemStack` as a side-effect_.  There's a simple experiment you can try; change your `System.out.println(id);` line to be `system.out.println(getID(is));` and see if it still prints the expected value.  I'm guessing it will print `null`.

Comment: it doesn't print null this prints the ID I have given to that ItemStack. And it perfectly matches the ID in the json string